# How to delete socket from javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I delete https://mywebsite.com/assets/js/socket.io.js from this code? If I just delete it, my script not loading.

```
console.log('myWp loading ' + Date.now());
var x = document.createElement('script');
x.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js',
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(x),
x.onload = function() {
jq321 = jQuery.noConflict(!0);
var a = document.createElement('script');
a.src = 'https://mywebsite.com/assets/js/socket.io.js',
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(a),
a.onload = function() {
    var a = jq321('.myWpImportWidget').attr('id'),
        s = document.createElement('script');

    var attrLanguage = jq321('.myWpImportWidget').data('myWp-language');
    if(typeof attrLanguage !== 'undefined') { userLanguage = attrLanguage; }
..........
```

I don't need socket anymore. My code don't depend on that socket. I am getting error in console [prntscr.com/lorjuz](https://prntscr.com/lorjuz)

```
socket.io.js:2 GET http://file/socket.io/?sessionID=undefined&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MTYQAsH
```

It is full error message. I am getting only this error. Socket loading every time with wrong url, so I need to delete him from the code. But if delete this part of the code:

```
var a = document.createElement('script'); 
a.src = 'mywebsite.com/assets/js/socket.io.js', 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(a),
```

my script not working on front-end

Comment: What do you want to achieve by deleting that? And why do you add that in the first place?

Comment: @Andreas I don't need socket anymore

Comment: Any other part of your code that is dependent on that socket? Because the code snippet that you provide, does not have anything to do with the socket. Also, any error messages associated with this issue?

Comment: @Andreas no, my code don't depend on that socket. Yes, I am getting error in console http://prntscr.com/lorjuz

Comment: @Andreas 
GET http://file/socket.io/?sessionID=undefined&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MTYKlrl net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it is full error message. I am getting only this error. Socket loading every time with wrong url, so I need to delete him from the code. But if delete this part of the code:

var a = document.createElement('script');
a.src = 'https://mywebsite.com/assets/js/socket.io.js',
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(a),

my script not working on front-end

Comment: @Andreas check please

Comment: Seems like `a.onload` will have no reference to `a` if you delete `var a = document.createElement('script');` so that function might never get executed

Comment: @Andreas In this case I am getting error 

Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined at HTMLScriptElement.x.onload (wid.js?v=0.133:73)
x.onload @ wid.js?v=0.133:73
load (async)
(anonymous) @ wid.js?v=0.133:70

Comment: Yes, you need to fix your code regarding anything related to that `a` variable. That is the reason why it is not working. And that is the error message that you are also suppose to include